Yahoo finance data in Google sheets
I'm not very experienced in writing scripts, but using AI I wanted to create a script that would download data from Yahoo Finance to Google Sheets in the following format:
Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Adj Close | Volume
Unfortunately, the script worked for a day and now when I run the script I get an error
{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"unauthorized","description":"User is not logged in"}}}
How to fix it to download data every one hour?
Script looks like below:
function importYahooFinanceData() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const newSheetName = "WTI_Price_calc";

  // Checking if we are on the right sheet
  if (sheet.getName() !== newSheetName) {
    return; // Script abort if sheet doesn't have proper name
  }

  // Defining the URL before use
  const url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/CL%3DF?period1=0&period2=9999999999&interval=1d&events=history";
  
  // Data download
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(response.getContentText());

  // Calculating a date 365 days ago
  const today = new Date();
  const past365Days = new Date(today);
  past365Days.setDate(today.getDate() - 365);

  // Filtering data from the last 365 days
  const filteredData = csvData.filter(row => {
    const date = new Date(row[0]);
    return date >= past365Days && row.every(cell => cell !== "null");
  }).slice(1);

  // Sorting data from newest to oldest
  filteredData.sort((a, b) => new Date(b[0]) - new Date(a[0]));

  // Deleting only data in columns A-G
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 7).clearContent();

  // Inserting new data, leaving columns H and beyond untouched
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, filteredData.length, filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
}
const url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/CL%3DF?period1=0&period2=9999999999&interval=1d&events=history";
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
Logger.log(response.getContentText());




Have you looked at GOOGLEFINANCE?

{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"unauthorized","description":"User is not logged in"}}} This error message is generated by Yahoo Finance. It has nothing to do with Google Sheets or API. You need to be logged in to Yahoo Finance.

OIL.WTI is not listed on GOOGLEFINANCE

I have been logged, but it still doesn't work
